# With Windows 7 & VS2015: alternative to debugging a tablet app?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, winrt-xaml, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I'm currently learning how to develop a simple application that will run in a 7-inch Windows 10 tablet. An opportunity came up to develop a simple application to run in a tablet. Instead of paying someone to do it, I decided to give it a try and do the work myself.

With that said, I have `Windows 7 Professional` and `VS2015`. I understand that I cannot debug a Windows 10 app locally (in this case a tablet app), which means that I would need to purchase a Windows 10 tablet to debug locally or upgrade to Windows 10.

Is this correct? And if so, is there any way to debug this app without having to buy the tablet or do the upgrade?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. You can build a Windows 10 using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2015, but you cannot debug without an attached device. The only way to otherwise debug this app is to upgrade your development machine to Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for claifying.